# Soma (Horas, minutos e segundos) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tarde, galera.

Então, construí uma query que realiza um cálculo para obter o tempo entre um checkin e checkout.
A data/hora é gravada no mesmo campo, seja no checkin ou no checkout. Logo, tive que fazer um LEAD e PARTITION BY para poder separar, até ai está resolvido.
Consigo obter separadamente a diferença em horas, minutos e segundos, mas não gostaria que fosse dessa forma, mas sim tudo junto.

Abaixo a query:

```html
WITH T_REPRES
AS (
    SELECT USU.CODIGO_ACESSO
        ,USU.USUARIO
        ,USU.CODIGO
    FROM DB_USUARIO USU
        --WHERE USU.NIVEL_REPRESENTANTE IN (@IDESTRUTURA)
    )
SELECT T2.USUARIO
    ,T2.DATA AS PERIODO
    ,T2.FUNCIONALIDADE
    ,T2.DATA_CHECKOUT
    ,CONCAT((DATEDIFF(HOUR, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT, T2.DATA) / 24) * -1
        ,':'
        ,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT, T2.DATA) % 60) * -1
        ,':'
        ,(DATEDIFF(SECOND, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT, T2.DATA) % 60) * -1
    ) AS CONCATEADO
FROM (
    SELECT T1.USUARIO
        ,T1.DATA
        ,T1.FUNCIONALIDADE
        ,LEAD(T1.DATA) OVER (
            PARTITION BY T1.USUARIO
            ,CAST(T1.DATA AS DATE) ORDER BY T1.USUARIO
                ,T1.DATA
                ,T1.FUNCIONALIDADE
            ) DATA_CHECKOUT
    FROM (
        SELECT REP.USUARIO
            ,TE.DATA
            ,TE.FUNCIONALIDADE
            ,TE.CODIGO_CLIENTE
        FROM DB_MOB_TIMELINE_EVENTOS TE
            ,T_REPRES REP
        WHERE TE.FUNCIONALIDADE IN (
                'CHECKIN'
                ,'CHECKOUT'
                )
            AND TE.USUARIO = REP.USUARIO
        ) T1
    ) T2
WHERE T2.DATA_CHECKOUT IS NOT NULL
    AND CAST(T2.DATA AS DATE) = '2023-04-17'
```

O resultado está abaixo:

[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ajvp.png)

**Gostaria de ter um resultado somando todo esse retorno concatenado, exemplo: 00:35:54. Todas as horas, minutos e segundos. Caso der mais que 60 segundos, contar mais um minuto. Caso der mais que 60 minuto, contar uma hora.**

Alguém poderia me ajudar?